# How to make global empty integer?

Tags: python, if-statement, integer, global-variables, declaration

How to declare global empty integer? I have simple code but i don't know how to declare a variable before def. In java I can do just that: public int a; 
but how to do it in python? Without this, the third if not working

My code:

```
def abcd:
if s<0.72:
    if e>30:
        a=0
        return a

    else:
        a=0
        return a
else:
    if a == 1:
        a = 1
        return a
    else:
        a=1
        return a
while True:
abcd
```

Comment: A variable doesn't exist until you assign a value; there is no such thing as an uninitialized variable in Python.

Comment: There are no variable declarations in Python either.

Answer (score 10):

**Python** is dynamic, so you don't need to declare things; they exist automatically in the first scope where they're assigned. So, all you need is a regular old assignment statement as above.

You can declare as follow, if you want a non-value variable:

```
a = None
```

Or you can declare as follow, if you want a zero value int variable:

```
a = int()
```

Comment: Ok but how make global variable? I need to set a as global variable. How to do it?

Comment: Put on of my examples in the top of your abcd function and it will be a global variable.

Comment: If I do this with every function execution, it will start with an empty value. I want each function to be executed value a, it has changed according to what is in the functions if. When I do as you say every time a it will be empty.

Comment: No you are wrong if you set variable a as global it will keep the value until you change it's value in a function.

Comment: def abcd(a =None): like this? @Fady Saad

Comment: No, in this way it will be an argument with local scope to the function scope. you should declare the a variable above the function declaration, in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

At the top:

`a = int()`

`int()` returns 0 to start.

Also, you need to use proper function syntax:

```
def abcd():
```

If `e` or `s` are arguments passed to `abcd`, you need to add those to the function signature:

```
def abcd(e, s):
```

Comment: I did this and continue on the third if I have: unresolved reference 'a'

Comment: File > Invalidate Caches... and restarting PyCharm helps.

Comment: @F.Fipoo the issue is you are creating a local variable. You must use the `global` directive for your function to work.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga but how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Python is a dynamic language with duck typing. So if you gonna declare an empty variable use `None` as it's initial value. That means no value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes dont make it equal to zero, depending on what you are doing your program will not work if equal to zero.
REMEMBER ZERO IS NOT THE SAME AS NONE